# Prove that $\frac{1}{x}$ does not have an upper bound

Tags: proof-verification, inverse-function, upper-lower-bounds

I just read at the library how to prove that $\frac{1}{x}$ does not have an upper bound. The idea was to use proof by contradiction. I tried to do the exercise one more time at home, and now I am not sure anymore if my solution is correct. Here is my attempt:

> Given the function $f=\frac{1}{x}$ defined on the interval
>   $I=]{0,+\infty}[$
>
> We suppose that this function has an upper bound $M$, which means that
>   $$\forall x \in I \quad \frac{1}{x} \leq M$$
>
> We can consider only the case when $M \gt 0$ because $\forall x \in I$
>   $\quad \frac{1}{x} \gt0$
>
> Because $M$ is an upper bound, we have $$M+1 \le\frac{1}{x}$$ but that
>   means that $M+1 \le\frac{1}{x}\le M$ which is a contradiction.

Is this correct?

Comment: How does  $M$ being an upper bound imply $M+1 \leq \frac1x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is not correct.
However, you can take: $$x = \frac{1}{M+1}$$
So that:
$$\frac{1}{x}= M+1 > M$$
A contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean:

Assume $\exists M>0$ such that
$$\forall x\in ]0,\infty[: \frac{1}{x}\leq M$$
Let $$x=\frac{1}{M+1}\in]0,\infty[$$
Now
$$\frac{1}{x}=M+1\not\leq M\implies\text{contradiction}$$

Answer (score 1):

The start was OK, we assume $\frac{1}{x}\le M$ for all positive numbers $x$, where $M$ is a positive number. This implies $\frac{1}{M}\le x$ for all positive numbers $x$. But since $\frac{1}{M}$ is positive, we can always find a positive number $x$ with $x< \frac{1}{M}$. So, we get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is not correct. $M$ being an upper bound does not imply that $M+1 \leq\frac1x$. Upper bound is not unique. In fact, $M$ being an upper bound implies that $M+1$ is also an upper bound as $M < M+1.$

A correct way would be:

$$\frac1x\leq M\\\frac1M \leq x$$ for all $x>0.$ Thus, $$\frac1M=0$$ which is a contradiction.